# Coverlet - dotnet test output to console

Tags: coverlet

I've been playing around with coverlet.  I can save the full details to a file (such as coverage.json) and I can see a summary table in the console.

I cannot figure out how to see the full coverage details in the console in table format.

The command: `dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true` shows the summary table, is it possible to add a flag and see a more detailed table including folders, files, and then classes?

I've looked through the documentation, including https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/blob/b02505932110c7231f946e06585460c6227f2e5d/Documentation/MSBuildIntegration.md, but cannot find anything.

Thanks.